# How do you say "Damsel in distress" in Korean?

Tags: vocabulary

Damsel in distress is used as a phrase to mean a woman who needs to be rescued by a man. Damsel is a woman with victim mentality.

Comment: Err... I think _damsel_ just means a young lady.

Comment: @jick Damsel might be a young lady but "damsel in distress" is a phrase which means a young woman who is in trouble and needs a man's help. (from Cambridge Dictionary)

Comment: Well, yes, "damsel in distress" is such a phrase, but the word "damsel" doesn't mean "in distress" - also, there's a difference between "in distress/in trouble" and "victim mentality" ...

Comment: What I meant is that the Damsel in "Damsel in distress" has victim mentality

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a perfect phrase in Korean that holds meaning & a broader tone of "Damsel in distress".

Some phrases that I can think of are below.

- 위기에 빠진 여성
- 붙잡힌 아가씨
- 곤경에 빠진 그녀

You would almost rarely use or hear these phrases in real-life conversations similar to how you seldom use "Damsel in distress", but they can be sometimes found in writings, literature, books, or movies.

Comment: I agree with this answer. You can also refer to the Korean Wikipedia Page for this phrase. https://ko.wikipedia.org/wiki/%EB%B9%84%ED%83%84%EC%97%90_%EB%B9%A0%EC%A7%84_%EC%86%8C%EB%85%80

Comment: Hmm... that Wikipedia page needs some serious cleanup.  Also 비탄 (grief/anguish) is probably not the correct word to use here...